# How do you sort for row details in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I am using [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) to sort my columns in table.

Now I have a table as follows:

```
<table class="sortable draggable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-salesOrderId">Order Number</th>
            <th class="col-orderDate">Date of Order</th>
            <th class="col-party">Party</th>
            <th class="col-edit">Edit</th>
            <th class="col-delete">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {#orders}
        <tr>
            <td class="col-salesOrderId">{.salesOrderId}</td>
            <td class="col-orderDate">{@formatDate date=orderDate format="DD-MM-YYYY" /}</td>
            <td class="col-party">{.party.partyName}</td>
            <td class="col-edit">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-edit">
                    &nbsp;
                </button>
            </td>
            <td class="col-delete">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete">
                    &nbsp;
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-details">
          <td>{.salesOrderId}</td>
          <td colspan="4">
            <table class="sortable draggable">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th class="col-itemName">Item Name</th>
                      <th class="col-quantity">Quantity</th>
                      <th class="col-rate">Rate</th>
                      <th class="col-amount">Amount</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {#items}
                    <tr>
                      <td>{.item.itemName}</td>
                      <td>{.quantity}</td>
                      <td>{.rate}</td>
                      <td>{@math key="{.quantity}" method="multiply" operand="{.rate}"/}</td>
                    </tr>
                  {/items}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        {/orders}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Have you noted in the above mentioned table I have row details for each row?
Now when I click on a column header to sort it, I get the row details first and then I get all the main rows.

Here is how my table looks before sorting:

[image]

Here is how my table looks after sorting:

[image]

Is there any solution to this problem still using sorttable?

**Update:**

Here is sample [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/oxfqmfrz/11/)

Row details are now sorted correctly as shown in the above jsFiddle. But now the problem is :

When you click on `City column` everything looks fine. Now if we again click on City Column, the row details are displayed before the actual rows which is wrong.

Please look at the images below for more information on problem:

After Clicking on City Column: (Which looks perfect)

[image]

After Clicking on City Column Again: (Expected for a developer but unexpected for a user)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I'am guessing but maybe the problem is the empty td beside the row details. I added first name as value and set css style **display:none**. Now the row details will be sorted also correctly.</s>

**Updated answer:** 
try to just nest the table inside the td like the below example.

Try this:

```
                <table class="sortable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Vishal</td>
            <td> Sherathiya
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Degree</th>
                    <th>Percentage</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>B.E.</td>
                    <td>67</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Nikunj</td>
            <td>Ramani
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Degree</th>
                    <th>Percentage</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>B.E.</td>
                    <td>80</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>M.E.</td>
                    <td>54</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Raj</td>
            <td>Gosai</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: That works great : See the updated fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/oxfqmfrz/9/ But now there is 1 more problem that can be solved. When sorting in descending order, the row details are shown before the actual row. Can you please try to do that??

Comment: Sorry for the late answer :)) Try that instead maybe you get closer to a solution.

Comment: At last I just changed my mind. I hide all the row details and show it only for the selected row. I used jQuery for that. Thanks for your time and hardwork.